# How to fix this recursive function

Tags: reactjs, recursion, settimeout

I'm trying to create a simple recursive function that adds random numbers to an array until the sum of that array is 10.

```js
function App() {
    const [array, setArray] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
    const [sum, setSum] = useState(0);

    const getRandNum = () => {
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        setArray((prev) => [...prev, num]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setSum(() => {
            return array.reduce(
                (acumulator, currentValue) => acumulator + currentValue,
                0
            );
        });
    }, [array]);

    const func = () => {
        if (sum >= 10) return;

        setTimeout(() => {
            getRandNum();
            func();
        }, 500);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div className="App">
                {array.map((num) => (
                    <p>{num}</p>
                ))}
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => func()}>click</button>
            <p>sum: {sum}</p>
        </>
    );
}
```

This recursive function `func()` does not stop calling itself. It keeps adding numbers even though `sum` is greater than 10.

I know what's the problem but I don't know how to fix it. If I add `console.log` into `func` like this:

```js
const func = () => {
    if (sum >= 10) return;

    setTimeout(() => {
        getRandNum();
        console.log(array, sum);
        func();
    }, 500);
};
```

It always logs the same numbers: `[1,2,3] 6`. So even though array and sum are changing, function keeps calling itself with same values and it does not stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to reference the new values that are put in state. Doing just `getRandNum();` means that you don't have access to them elsewhere in that block; you might be triggering a re-render, but that `func` function still [closes over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) the value `array` had at the moment `func` was first invoked.

A good way to do this would be to add another state - a boolean flag that indicates whether you're in the process of adding values or not. Check that state on every render and perform the psuedo-recursive asynchronous update if needed.

Also, the `sum` state is superfluous, because it depends entirely on another state, `array`. ([Don't duplicate state!](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure)) Use `useMemo` instead to indicate the dependency and calculate it synchronously.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useMemo } = React;
function App() {
    const [array, setArray] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
    const sum = useMemo(() => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0), [array]);
    const [funcRunning, setFuncRunning] = useState(false);
    const getRandNum = () => {
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        setArray((prev) => [...prev, num]);
    };
    // Run on every render:
    useEffect(() => {
        if (funcRunning) {
            if (sum >= 10) {
                setFuncRunning(false);
                return;
            }
            const timeoutId = setTimeout(getRandNum, 500);
            return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="App">
                {array.map((num, i) => (
                    <p key={i}>{num}</p>
                ))}
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => setFuncRunning(true)}>click</button>
            <p>sum: {sum}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```